# get_terms that have custom sticky field checked

Tags: custom-field, taxonomy, terms

I was able to add a extra custom field, named `sticky`, to a custom taxonomy, using the [wp taxonomy meta](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/taxonomy-meta-script-for-wordpress/) plugin, like this:

```
function YOUR_PREFIX_register_taxonomy_meta_boxes()
{
    // Make sure there's no errors when the plugin is deactivated or during upgrade
    if ( !class_exists( 'RW_Taxonomy_Meta' ) )
        return;

    $meta_sections = array();

    // First meta section
    $meta_sections[] = array(
        'title'      => 'Sticky',             // section title
        'taxonomies' => array('tvr_amenity'), // list of taxonomies. Default is array('category', 'post_tag'). Optional
        'id'         => 'sticky',                 // ID of each section, will be the option name

        'fields' => array(                             // List of meta fields
            array(
                'name' => 'Show in home filters',
                'id'   => 'sticky',
                'type' => 'checkbox',
            ),
        ),
    );
    foreach ( $meta_sections as $meta_section )
    {
        new RW_Taxonomy_Meta( $meta_section );
    }
}
```

[image]

Now I'm trying to get all the taxonomies that has this value checked, like this:

```
$types = $types = get_terms( 'tvr_amenity', array(
    'parent'    => '0',
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    'sticky' => 1
 ) );
```

But the filter is ignored (all the parent taxonomies are shown), it returns the exact same than:

```
$types = $types = get_terms( 'tvr_amenity', array(
        'parent'    => '0',
        'hide_empty' => 1
     ) );
```

Any idea what I'm missing, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, got it

```
<?php
    $types = get_terms( 
        'tvr_amenity', 
        array(
            'parent'    => '0',
            'hide_empty' => 1

         )
    );
    foreach( $types as $type ) :
            $myname = trim($type->name);
            $meta = get_option('amenity_sticky');
            if (empty($meta)) $meta = array();
            if (!is_array($meta)) $meta = (array) $meta;
            $meta = isset($meta[$type->term_id]) ? $meta[$type->term_id] : array();
            $value = $meta['is_sticky'];
            if(!$value) continue; /* skip term if is_sticky not checked */
?>
    <p>
    <input type='checkbox' name="apartment_amenity[]" value='<?php echo $type->term_id ?>' class='tvr_amenity'> <?php echo $myname ?>
    </p>
<?php endforeach;   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first change this:

```
// First meta section
$meta_sections[] = array(
    'title'      => 'Sticky',             // section title
    'taxonomies' => array('tvr_amenity'), // list of taxonomies. Default is array('category', 'post_tag'). Optional
    'id'         => 'amenity_sticky',                 // ID of each section, will be the option name

    'fields' => array(                             // List of meta fields
        array(
            'name' => 'Show in home filters',
            'id'   => 'is_sticky',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
        ),
    ),
);
foreach ( $meta_sections as $meta_section )
{
    new RW_Taxonomy_Meta( $meta_section );
}
```

To get the info in the front end I think this could be the solution:

```
            $terms = get_terms( 'tvr_amenity', array(
                'hide_empty' => 0,
            ) );
            foreach( (array) $terms as $term) {
                $meta = get_option('tvr_amenity');
                if (empty($meta)) $meta = array();
                if (!is_array($meta)) $meta = (array) $meta;
                $meta = isset($meta[$term->term_id]) ? $meta[$term->term_id] : array();
                $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'tvr_amenity' );
                $is_sticky = $meta['is_aticky'];
                $is_sticky_id = false;
                if (is_array($is_sticky)) {
                    foreach ($is_sticky as $att) {
                        $is_sticky_id = $att;
                    }
                } ?>
                <a class="term-link" href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>" class="<?php echo $is_sticky; ?>">
                <?php echo sprintf(__('%s', 'udla'), $term->name); ?>
                </a>
                <p><?php echo $term->description; ?></p>
            <?php
            }
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much for your answer, but this sill also return all the items (even if is_sticky is not checked), any idea?

Comment: Actually I made `print_r($term);` and `print_r($meta)` and there's no reference about is_sticky

Comment: add an `'include' => array(),` in the `get_terms` with the IDs you want to filter, or include you new meta field in the foreach :P sorry can´t help more